# How to set rewrite condition for url in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have below url.

```
http://localhost/testing/images/Latest+Images/In+Golden+Light/golden
```

Now i need rewrite condition in htaccess for this type of url 
Now i want to get category name(Latest+Images) and caption name(In+Golden+Light)
and search criteria is (golden) from this url. How can i get this ?
Can any one please give me answer for this problem.

Comment: What is your internal URI that supports all these parameters like category, caption, search criteria etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect all urls to the index.php with this simple rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then split the url with the explode function:

```
$parts = explode("/",$_GET['url']);
```

Now the category name is in $parts[2], the caption name is in $parts[3] and the search criteria is in $parts[4].

(assuming that all links have exactly 5 parts)